# Reader onload function not adding split lines to predefined Array

Tags: javascript, html, input, text, readfile

I am trying to load a file using the input tag in html with type 'file'

```html
<input type="file">
```

And then with this file, I am trying to split each line and return the resulting array into an array called `lines`.

I have tried moving the console.log(lines) around but I only get the correct result when the console.log is inside the .onload function.

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')
input.addEventListener('change', function (e) {

    let lines = new Array();
    console.log(input.files)
    const reader = new FileReader()

    reader.onload = function () {
        lines = reader.result.split('\n');
    }

    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
    console.log(lines)
})
```

How can i ensure that the `lines` array has had the correct split lines put into it so that I can then use the `lines` array in other parts of my overall function

Comment: use double quotes instead of single may be this is the issue.

Comment: Just tried the return array is still empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try push split value in array. it may work for you.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')
let lines = [];
input.addEventListener('change', function (e) {

    
    
    const reader = new FileReader()

    reader.onload = function () {
        lines.push(reader.result.split('\n'));
  
    }
reader.readAsText(input.files[0]); 
    
    console.log(lines);
})
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

Comment: @kquinn just open array in console you will see split array in that.

Comment: Ah i see perfect thank you! Do you have an explanation as to why this works? I thought this might not work as I thought the split function return a whole array and that the first element of the lines array would be the single split array, instead of each the split array element

Comment: @kquinn reader function return all element as array and now we have to just push that element to our custom array.